# SQLAlchemy Retrieving Different Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_username = "my_username"
db_pw = "my_password"
db_to_use = "my_database"
#####
engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql://" +
    db_username + ":" +
    db_pw +
    "@localhost:5432/" +
    db_to_use
    )
#####
connection = engine.connect()
fac_id_list = connection.execute (
    """
        select distinct
            a.name,
            replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(a.logo_url,'.*/logo','','i'),'production.*','','i'),'/','') as new_logo
        from
            sync_locations as a
        inner join
            public.vw_locations as b
            on
                a.name = b.location_name
        order by
             new_logo
        """
)
```

I want to put the results of `fac_id_list` into two separate lists. One list will contain all of the values from `a.name` and the other `new_logo`.

How can I do this?

```
sql_results = []
for row in fac_id_list:
     sql_results.append(row)
```

This puts every column in my SQL query into a list, but I want them separated.

Comment: Loop through the results, appending each element of the row onto the appropriate list.

Comment: e.g. `names.append(row[0])`

Comment: That was my idea, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Then you clearly need to read a tutorial on how to process the results of a sqlalchemy query. `for row in fac_id_list:...`

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html

Comment: I know, that's just the generic close reason we use for questions that don't include their own attempt, because there isn't one whose description matches better (it replaced a previous close reason that was more descriptive of this case).

Comment: Where is the part where you attempt to append each column to different lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loop over the results, you can spread them into separate variables and append them to the corresponding lists

```
names = []
logos = []
for name, logo in fac_id_list:
    names.append(name)
    logos.append(log)
```

Comment: I went through the link, is there a particular section that I need to look at?

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#invoking-sql-strings-directly-to-the-driver

Comment: I just don't have much experience working with SQLAlchemy and I don't feel like the documentation is very good.

Comment: This isn't really a sqlalchemy issue, this is just Python looping.

Comment: It's no different than if you did `fac_id_list = [[name1, logo1], [name2, logo2], ...]`

Comment: I wasn't sure how to pull the column separately from the result.

Comment: You can either use spreading like I did, or indexing like `row[0]` and `row[1]`.

Comment: This was literally all I needed. I don't find the documentation helpful and I don't have much experience working with SQLAlchemy. Literally just needed to know how to pull separate columns from my result.